# Google Chrome mixed-content error on HTTPS

Tags: google-chrome, http, https, mixed-content

I enabled SSL on my website which is hosted on Blogspot with a custom domain and I encounter this error in console which asks me to Load Unsafe Scripts on the address bar.

What I see in Inspect Element:

[image: What I see in Inspect Element.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with IPv4. The error just says that, while your page was served over `https`, it's trying to load an external script via `http`, which Chrome doesn't allow. You must modify your page to load all resources over `https`.

Comment: Yes, I enabled Force HTTPs kinda thing on cloudflare. Didn't fix it though

Comment: You need to modify your page's HTML to load the scripts over HTTPS (e.g. <script src="https://........>)